# Linked MySQL tables into PHP arrays

Tags: php, mysql, json, join, multidimensional-array

I have two tables and a linking (intermediate) table:

```
manufacturer                     car
+----+-----------+---------+     +----+----------+-------+
| id | make      | founded |     | id | model    | debut |
+----+-----------+---------+     +----+----------+-------+
| 1  | Ford      | 1903    |     | 1  | Model T  | 1908  |
| 2  | Chevrolet | 1911    |     | 2  | Series C | 1913  |
| 3  | Honda     | 1946    |     | 3  | Mustang  | 1962  |
|    |           |         |     | 4  | Camaro   | 1966  |
|    |           |         |     | 5  | Model G  | 1924  |
+----+-----------+---------+     +----+----------+-------+


manufacturer_car
+----+-----------------+--------+
| id | manufacturer_id | car_id |
+----+-----------------+--------+
| 1  | 1               | 1      |
| 2  | 2               | 2      |
| 3  | 1               | 3      |
| 4  | 2               | 4      |
+----+-----------------+--------+
```

Note: Honda doesn't have any cars. Model G (Toyota) doesn't correspond to any manufacturers.

I would like to create a multidimentional array in PHP of these linked tables. Car matches will be an array within the manufacturer array. I'm not sure how to represent that type of array in PHP, the following is a JSON representation:

```
[
  {
    "manufacturer": "Ford",
    "founded":      "1903",
    "cars":[
      {
        "model":    "Model T",
        "debut":  "1908"
      },
      {
        "model":    "Mustang",
        "debut":  "1962"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "manufacturer": "Chevrolet",
    "founded":      "1911",
    "cars":[
      {
        "model":    "Series C",
        "debut":  "1913"
      },
      {
        "model":    "Camaro",
        "debut":  "1966"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "manufacturer": "Honda",
    "founded":      "1946",
    "cars":[

    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried:

```
$query = "SELECT
            manufacturer.make,
            manufacturer.founded,
            car.model,
            car.debut
          FROM
            manufacturer
          LEFT JOIN manufacturer_car
            INNER JOIN car
            ON manufacturer_car.car_id = car.id
            ON manufacturer_car.manufacturer_id = manufacturer.id";

$rows = array();

if ($result = $connection->query($query)) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rows[] = $row;
  }
}

// Print array
print_r($rows);
```

But this results in:

```
[0] => Array                |  [1] => Array
  (                         |    (
    [manufacturer] => Ford  |      [manufacturer] => Ford
    [founded] => 1903       |      [founded] => 1903
    [model] => Model T      |      [model] => Mustang
    [debut] => 1908         |      [debut] => 1962
  )                         |    )
```

Instead of what, I imagine, should look like:

```
[0] => Array
  (
    [manufacturer] => Ford
    [founded] => 1903
    [cars] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
          (
            [model] => Model T
            [debut] => 1908
          )
        [1] => Array
          (
            [model] => Mustang
            [debut] => 1962
          )
      )
  )
```

The final output will be JSON, like the example above.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you made the result array an associative array whose keys are the manufacturers.

Buty the main issue is that you need to append the car information to the `cars` element of the array element within the manufacturer-specific element.

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = $row->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (!isset($rows[$row['make']])) {
        $rows[$row['make']] = array(
            'manufacturer' => $row['make'],
            'founded' => $row['founded'],
            'cars' => array()
        );
    }
    if ($row['model']) {
        $rows[$row['make']]['cars'][] = array(
            'model' => $row['model'],
            'debut' => $row['debut']
        );
    }
}
```

If you want an indexed array instead of associative, you can do:

```
$rows = array_values($rows);
```

after the loop.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. A few things, please correct me if I'm wrong: 1) `$rows[$row['manufacturer']]` should be `$rows[$row['id']]` or another unique row. 2) the final if statement `if ($row['model']) {}` creates an array separate of the current row.

Comment: 1) There is no `id` in your `SELECT`, so there's no `$row['id']`. 2) That checks whether `model` is `NULL`, which will happen for manufacturers that have no cars, so it doesn't create a null entry in `cars`.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, I apologize. I've added an update to the question based on your answer.

Comment: Yeah, `$row['manufacturer']` was a mistake, should be `$row['make']`. But the desired output in your question says `"car":    "Series C",` not `"model":    "Series C"`,

Comment: `$row['cars'][]` should have been `$rows[$row['make']]['cars'][]`. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: You're right, I missed that. I've updated the question. Your answer works great. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've updated the answer to match the updated question.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that what you want is not possible using sql statements because of the way that join works, but you can process the info you get from the query like this:

```
$manufacturer='';
$actualRow=-1;
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   if($manufacturer!==$row['manufacturer']){
     $rows[] = array('manufacturer'=>$row['manufacturer'],
                     'founded'=>$row['founded'],
                      'car'=>array($row['car']));
     $actualRow++;
   }else{
     $rows[$actualRow][car][]=$row['car'];
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps